# Create a class instance from string when files containing class are 'required' run-time in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, minitest

I am writing some test cases in ruby using Minitest FW. In the setup routine, I try to require all the ruby files which have the classes of which I wish to create instances (by string name) in each test case. I get the error saying uninitialized constant 'class name'. I can understand that this might not be the best practice, However, I am curious and want to know what I doing wrong. Below is the code I am working on.

```
# Native.rb
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Native_Test < Minitest::Unit::TestCase

 def setup
  path = Dir.getwd
  Dir[File.join(path + '*test.rb')].each {|file| require file} # requiring all files
 end

 def test_tc1
  puts 'Hi'
  method_name = 'verifyLogic1'
  class_name = 'My_work1'
  obj = Object.const_get(class_name).new  # -> undefined constant My_work1 
  obj.method_name('1','2')
 end

 def test_tc2
  ..
 end
end

# validate_1_test.rb
class My_work1
 def verifyLogic1(arg1,arg2)
  puts 'arg1'
  puts 'arg2'
 end
end
```

Please correct me wherever I am wrong. More than happy to accept any inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly:

```
path + '*test.rb'
```

This will end up with: `current/folder*test.rb`. Instead do:

```
File.join path, '*test.rb'
```

Secondly, this:

```
obj.method_name('1','2')
```

will not work, as you will try to execute method `method_name` on the object. You need to use `send` or even better `public_send':

```
obj.public_send(method_name, '1', '2')
```

Few more notes: There are 3 types of common naming conventions in ruby. CamelCase, snake_case or ALL_CAPITAL. CamelCase should be used for class names, snake_case for variables and methods and ALL_CAPITALS for other constants (unless like me you prefer to use CamelCase for all constants).

Comment: Works. Appreciate it !